# Did I bust my new hard drive? (Ultra DMA CRC Error Count)

Tags: external-hard-drive

I have a new 3TB hard drive (external | 3.5 In | SATA | NOT SSD) and was transferring from old disk to new, across a network when my system BSODed referring to a tcpip.sys fault.

When I rebooted, the disk would show up as Not Initialised in Disk Management (Win7). This is after I had partitioned it and written about a TB worth of data to it.

No tools would pick it up (chkdsk, testdrive, seagate disk wizard, seagate tools for windows, diskpart, linux, pmagic via usb boot drive, etc) finally i read a forum post that recommended HD Tune Pro and while the partitions were munched it did give me some SMART readout as below:

Using that info I was able to determine that the drive controllers on the external hd case were kaput. I switched out my drive to another case and was then able to do a chkdsk /f on the drive and now all my bits are in order. The drive *works* my 3 partitions are back.

However even after rebooting etc I still get a warning in HD Tune Pro re: (Ultra DMA CRC Error Count) as below.

So

1. is this something i should be concerned about?
2. Is this now a permanent blemish on this drives record?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Swap your cable](http://www.overclock.net/t/706633/ultra-dma-crc-error-count), or at least re-seat it.  Default-out your BIOS as well before you consider replacing a component.
This immediately seemed like an interface issue.